# Get function signature and parameters from within current function in Python

Tags: python, signature

I'm trying to get all function parameters and their values from within the current function in Python and almost have it working except for one thing:  I don't know how to call it from inside the function without explicitly giving it the name of the object.

For example:  the code below works for the case of the function being a class method ("my_func_in_class", but I don't know what to pass into the inspect.signature() call for the "my_func" function that is not part of a class without mentioning the function by name.

This isn't critical to solving my problem at hand but I'd still like to know how to make it work

```
import inspect
import sys

def my_func(a, b, c=None):

    this_func = inspect.currentframe()
    func_name = inspect.getframeinfo(this_func).function
    print(f"Function Name {func_name}")

    (sig, local_vars) = inspect.signature(my_func), locals()

    args = {}
    for a in sig.parameters.keys():
        args[a] = local_vars[a]

    return args

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def my_func_in_class(self, a, b, c=None):

        this_func = inspect.currentframe()
        func_name = inspect.getframeinfo(this_func).function
        print(f"Function Name {func_name}")
        (sig, local_vars) = inspect.signature(getattr(self, func_name)), locals()

        args = {}
        for a in sig.parameters.keys():
            args[a] = local_vars[a]

        return args

if __name__ == "__main__":

    class1 = MyClass()
    args1 = my_func(1, 2)
    args2 = class1.my_func_in_class(10, 20, c=30)

    print(f"args1:")
    for (k, v) in args1.items():
        print(f"{k}: {v}")

    print(f"\nargs2")
    for (k, v) in args2.items():
        print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

```
python ./get_func_args.py
Function Name my_func
Function Name my_func_in_class
args1:
a: 1
b: 2
c: None

args2
a: 10
b: 20
c: 30
```

But:

```
def my_func(a, b, c=None):

    this_func = inspect.currentframe()
    func_name = inspect.getframeinfo(this_func).function
    print(f"Function Name {func_name}")

    (sig, local_vars) = inspect.signature(this_func), locals()
```

returns the error:

```
Function Name my_func
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_func_args.py", line 41, in <module>
    args1 = my_func(1, 2)
  File "./get_func_args.py", line 12, in my_func
    (sig, local_vars) = inspect.signature(this_func), locals()
  File "/home/mlissa2/cmm/python/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 3065, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
  File "/home/mlissa2/cmm/python/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 2815, in from_callable
    follow_wrapper_chains=follow_wrapped)
  File "/home/mlissa2/cmm/python/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 2193, in _signature_from_callable
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: <frame object at 0x7ff7dcc92048> is not a callable object
```

So I'm very close but don't have the final step in place.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is to get arguments information from the signature of the function along with their values, then you don't need to use `inspect.signature()`. You can use the following approach.

```
def my_func(a, b, c=None):
    # get arg-values without reference to callable
    cframe = inspect.currentframe()
    args_info = inspect.getargvalues(cframe)

    # Collecting args-values of my_func in a dictionary
    this_func_argvals = {arg: args_info.locals.get(arg) for arg in args_info.args}
    return this_func_argvals
```

That's it.

However, if you must insist on getting the signature too for whatnot than use the following approach.

The reason you were able to get *my_func_in_class* reference in your class method was because your class provided access to its namespace, so getting attribute from that namespace was easy. In order to get reference of *my_func* we need to access namespace of the immediate outer stack of *my_func*. From there we can get *my_func* reference. Here's how to do that:

```
def some_fun(a, b, c=None):
    # Get Stacks. We only need FrameInfo for current frame and immediate outer frame
    stacks = inspect.stack()

    # Get my_func's name (str) from current frame
    this_func_name = stacks[0].function

    # Get immediate outer frame
    outer_frame = stacks[1].frame

    # From outer frame's locals, get reference to my_fun using its name as key
    this_func_reference = outer_frame.f_locals.get(this_func_name)

    # Voila!
    sigs = inspect.signature(this_func_reference)
```

Comment: Thank you!

I haven't had time to fully play around with your answer yet, but I will go at it piece by piece and really understand it.  My knowledge of how the stacks module works is sorely lacking.